# Phone Calls and Xib Files

Tags: iphone

I am using IB to make my views, I am just wondering how I can resize those views during a phone call to move under the green bar. Checking Resize subviews doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is called `doubleHeightStatusBar`.

Actually, you can watch these app delegates: `application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:` and `application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:`

Comment: I think he just means checking for the extended status bar.